# Postfix - block by sender email domain ip

Tags: postfix

For some time now I receive a lot of spam emails. The emails are all different but if I lookup the domain of the email address it always resolves to the same IP address.

So:

- xyz@domain1.tld -> resolves to 80.249.161.131
- ddfda@domain2.tld -> resolves to 80.249.161.131
- etc.

In postfix I can reject each email address but in this case it is not helpful because the email address changes all the time.

The next problem I have is that each email is send through a different mail server. So I cannot block by sender address.

What I would like to do is block an email by the ip address. Not that of the sender but of the ip address of the domain used as part of the email.

Any suggestions on how this is done in postfix?

Comment: Is it really so that all the domains resolve to the same IP address, but the messages are coming from different sources? That's unusual.

Comment: Yes, however, the domain name of the mail server also resolves to the same ip address. But the subdomain provided with the HELO points to a different ip address, which is the same address used to contact my mail server.

Comment: Couldn't you just block the offending IP address?

Comment: Well that was my question. Blocking 80.249.161.131 doesn't work because the mails do not come from that ip address. So how do I block those emails?

Comment: That's why it's better to block the actual source IP addresses.

Comment: I started this question because I don't know how to block these email addresses. If you know how it is done, please provide me with an example. Just repeating my initial problem is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_sender_a_access

Add

> smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_a_access
>   hash:/etc/postfix/sender_a_access

in your `main.cf`

and add

> 80.249.161      REJECT

in your `/etc/postfix/sender_a_access`

and call

> postmap /etc/postfix/sender_a_access

This will block the whole /24 subnet from that ip range where a lot of spam comes from.

I also use this for exactly the same ip range ;).